# zeros of sums of complex exponential functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Let $a_i,b_i$ be $n(\geq 2)$ non-zero real numbers. Assuming that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie^{\sqrt{-1}b_i x}=1$ has infinite real solutions for $x$, prove or disprove that $b_i(1\leq i\leq n)$ is linearly dependent over the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$. $n=2$ is true by easy computation.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: When I dealt with an integration by discretization, I got this problem. Although it's not relevant to the original question, I'm curious about this. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is true and follows from a theorem of G. Polya. See the very nice survey by Langer:

*Langer, R. E.*, [**On the zeros of exponential sums and integrals.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1931-05133-8), Bulletin A. M. S. 37, 213-239 (1931). [ZBL57.0416.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:57.0416.04).